# LU factorization with pivot to solve linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I read that LUP matrix exist for any square matrix such that it is not a singular one.
But I came across a matrix that when I get the LUP and calculate `Lz=Pb` -> `Ux = z` the answer is wrong, I don't know why.

The linear equation was like that

```
x+y+z=2
z=2
2x+3y+z=0
```

the matrix is like that

```
1  1  1
0  0  1
2  3  1
```

calculation with LUP gave out

```
x=-4, y=2, z=2
```

Though manual substitution calculations showed that the correct answer is

```
x=2,y=-2,z=2
```

Can any one tell me why this happens is it a calculation mistake or something or it is a limitation with the LU factorization?!

[Edit]
Attempt to solve:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow swap(r1,r3)$$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow  R_3 - \frac12 R_1$$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\  0 & - \frac12 &  \frac12\\ \end{bmatrix}\rightarrow swap(r2,r3)$$
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & - \frac12 &  \frac12  \\ 0 & 0 & 1  \\ \end{bmatrix} = U$$
$$L = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac12 & 1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$b = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2\\2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If you have $A = PLU$, then $Ax = b \Leftrightarrow LUx=P^{-1}b \Leftrightarrow Ly = P^{-1}b, Ux = y$. Specify what form of $PLU$-decomposition you have.

Comment: I have `Ax = b` then I took the `A` and got its `LU` then any row swapping I made to get the `LU` I also applied it to `b` then I made `Lz = b` then `Ux = z`

Comment: @Doggynub: On your update, what are you using as $P$?

Comment: I dont actually use $P$. When I make any swap I swap the $b$ matrix too, is this wrong?

Comment: @Doggynub: That is the problem! Take your $L \cdot U$ and see what it is. Is it $A$? Almost, with a permutation $P$. The $LU$ calculation will show you what $P$ you should be using and that indeed is the issue. Lastly, you should really look at an LU algorithm as these subtleties will get you every time! Regards

Comment: I see, but could you tell me what P should I use in the above ?! is it $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$??

Comment: @Doggynub: Look at your result when you multiply $L \cdot U$. What rows are out of whack? What can you do with $A = PLU$ to make your $LU$ actually be $A$. Do you know how a permutation matrix works? You can also take my $L, U$ below and see what they give you, then look at my $P$ and see what it is doing? Clear? Hint: What do you get if you multiply the $P$ you chose with your $L \cdot U$? You want  $P$ to have rows $(0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0)$. Try that $P$ with your $L$U and find $PLU$ and verify that that is the original $A$. Clear

Comment: Yes, now it is clear. I read the definition of permutation matrix wrong I thought it could only contains 1 as values, my fault.

Comment: @Doggynub: Also, look at your row swaps and the P I mention. See a pattern. If you keep track of these row swaps, you know P from those. Maybe you should review a permutation matrix write-up as this is very important! Hope everything is clear now! Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, we have:

$$A = P L U x = b \rightarrow LUx = P^{-1}b \rightarrow Ly = P^{-1}b, Ux = y$$

Note: you can see my $L$ and $U$ below.

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Using this, we have:

$Ly = P^{-1}\cdot b \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\\ y_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 0\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$

This will lead to $y = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -4 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$

Next we solve:

$Ux = y \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\\ x_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -4\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$

This will lead to $x= \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: but i made other swaps i swapped row 3 and row 1 first then zeroed column 1, then swapped row 2 and 3. Is this wrong?

Comment: You can swap rows, columns and anything you'd like, just as long as it is consistent and follows the rules for doing that, you should still get the correct result. Does What I did make sense? I will add my P also. Note, for this problem, since $z$ is fixed, you could have left that alone and made a $2x2$ system and that should work also and will be easier (less room for error). Regards

Comment: Ye what you did completely make sense but I wonder why what i did dont get it right(P make rows 3 1 2, then get the LU)!? though i followed the rules and it is really annoying me.

Comment: @Doggynub: Do you get the same $A = PLU$ that I got? Maybe, you can write out the steps as an update to your question that you used and I can try and spot what the issue is. Regards

Comment: ok, I will make that

Comment: Nice work, and supportive exchange, too! (+)